# Swipe Gestures not working android

Tags: android

I am working on an ImageView which is to render images in an arraylist based on the gesture used, for example left gesture loads image on position -1 of the array and vice versa, on top of that is a gesture Overlay, its being used to save and load other gestures such as "Shortcuts" to first image, last Image and more, the code was working perfectly until it stopped all the sudden below is my code:

SwipeListener File

```
public class OnSwipeListerner implements View.OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeListerner(Context context) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
        float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
        if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
            if (distanceX > 0)
                onSwipeRight();
            else
                onSwipeLeft();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

How I am using the SwipeListener Class:

```
    //swipe lock
private static final int SWIPE_LOCK = 100;
//swipe unlock
private static final int SWIPE_UNLOCK = 0;
//swipe lock key
private static final String SWIPLE_LOCK_SIG = "swipelock";
//swipe unlock key
private static final String SWIPLE_UNLOCK_SIG = "swipeunlock";
//finale sig
private int swipeSignal = 0;
.........

    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeListerner(this) {

        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft() {

          if (swipeSignal == SWIPE_UNLOCK)

            {
                try {
                    ImageItem item = getData().get(imagePosition = imagePosition + 1);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
                    titleTextView.setText(item.getTitle());

                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    ImageItem item = getData().get(imagePosition = imagePosition - 1);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
                    titleTextView.setText(item.getTitle());
                }
                Log.d(DetailsActivity.this.getPackageName(), "Swipe left image View");

           }else if (swipeSignal == SWIPE_LOCK)
           {
               Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, "Swipe Locked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeRight(){

            if (swipeSignal == SWIPE_UNLOCK){
            try {
                ImageItem item = getData().get(imagePosition = imagePosition - 1);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
                titleTextView.setText(item.getTitle());

            }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                ImageItem item = getData().get(imagePosition = imagePosition + 1);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
                titleTextView.setText(item.getTitle());
            }
            Log.d(DetailsActivity.this.getPackageName(), "Swipe Right image View");


       }else if (swipeSignal == SWIPE_LOCK)
       {
           Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, "Swipe Locked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
        }


    });



}

private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {
    final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
    TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);
    for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
        imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, "Image" + i));
    }
    return imageItems;
}

@Override
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {


ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gestureLibrary.recognize(gesture);

    if (predictions.size() > 0 && predictions.get(0).score > 1.0) {
            String result = predictions.get(0).name;

            Toast.makeText(this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                   .show();

        if(result.equalsIgnoreCase(SWIPLE_LOCK_SIG))
        {

           // swipeSignal = SWIPE_LOCK;

        }else if(result.equalsIgnoreCase(SWIPLE_UNLOCK_SIG))
        {

          //  swipeSignal = SWIPE_UNLOCK;


        }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the problem, GestureOverlayView creates some form of layer on the top of the XML just as GestureDetector needs some forms of listeners on the screen, the GestureOverlayView seems to be preventing the GestureDetector from detecting any gestures since its on the lower hierarchy, to the GestureDetector no gestures are being received and everything seems ok to it, to the GestureOverlayView all gestures are being received even the simple swipes which it cannot understand yet because it does not have code for them, its the GestureDetector that has their code, so my way out was removing the GestureOverlayView